# Does Python do variable interpolation similar to "string #{var}" in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, string-formatting, string-interpolation, language-comparisons

In Python, it is tedious to write:

```
print "foo is" + bar + '.'
```

Can I do something like this in Python?

`print "foo is #{bar}."`

Comment: I think I've found a solution, would you check it out?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504732/how-could-i-make-my-python-string-interpolation-implementation-work-accross-impo

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Python 3.6+ does have variable interpolation - prepend an `f` to your string:

```
f"foo is {bar}"
```

For versions of Python below this (Python 2 - 3.5) you can use `str.format` to pass in variables:

```
# Rather than this:
print("foo is #{bar}")

# You would do this:
print("foo is {}".format(bar))

# Or this:
print("foo is {bar}".format(bar=bar))

# Or this:
print("foo is %s" % (bar, ))

# Or even this:
print("foo is %(bar)s" % {"bar": bar})
```

Comment: The 3rd one looks neat, but I remember this way kinda deprecated? is that true?

Comment: There is also, for the lazy, `print "foo is %(bar)s" % locals()`.

Comment: @yozloy - correct it is deprecated in Python 3 (as I understand it).

Comment: @SeanVieira what's the over taker of this solution?

Comment: Strange the fact that Python has something explicit.

Comment: the % syntax is no longer deprecated in Python 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23381153/770425

Comment: What does "it is explicit rather than implicit" imply in this context? `print "foo is #{bar}."`, for example, looks very explicit to me

Comment: The quote-as-operator-context is what's implicit (to my mind) - `print "foo is #{bar}"` vs. `print 'foo is #{bar}'` is implicit compared to `"foo is {bar}".format(bar=bar)` or even Python 3.6's `f"foo is {bar}"`

Comment: This is incorrect since [3.6 introduced f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-20)

Answer (score 28):

Python 3.6 <del>will have</del> has [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) using *f-strings*:

```
print(f"foo is {bar}.")
```

Comment: In case anyone was wondering: yes, you can combine this with say raw strings, like so `rf"foo is {bar}"`.

Answer (score 11):

Python 3.6 has [introduced f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#no-use-of-globals-or-locals):

```
print(f"foo is {bar}.")
```

---

Old answer:

Since version 3.2 Python has [`str.format_map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) which together with [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) or [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) allows you to do fast:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
>>> bar = "something"
>>> print("foo is {bar}".format_map(locals()))
foo is something
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

I have learned the following technique from [Python Essential Reference](http://www.dabeaz.com/per.html):

```
>>> bar = "baz"
>>> print "foo is {bar}.".format(**vars())
foo is baz.
```

This is quite useful when we want to refer to many variables in the formatting string:

- We don't have to repeat all variables in the argument list again: compare it to the explicit keyword argument-based approaches (such as `"{x}{y}".format(x=x, y=y)` and `"%(x)%(y)" % {"x": x, "y": y}`).
- We don't have to check one by one if the order of variables in the argument list is consistent with their order in the formatting string: compare it to the positional argument-based approaches (such as `"{}{}".format(x, y)`, `"{0}{1}".format(x, y)` and `"%s%s" % (x, y)`).

Comment: That's an... odd way to pass in bar... Pretty neat though, makes it more closely follow the Ruby way.

Comment: This seems like the best solution if you're working with an object. For example, if you are reporting an urllib2.HTTPError you can do `"HTTP error: {error.code} {error.msg}".format(**vars())` This doesn't work with `format(**locals())`

Answer (score 5):

[String formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
>>> bar = 1
>>> print "foo is {}.".format(bar)
foo is 1.
```

Comment: or older but still popular:    print "foo is %s" % str(bar)

Comment: That's supposed to be deprecated by now, though I can't find the PEP.

Comment: Not deprecated, just superseded.

Comment: [I guess in Python 2 it's not](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#pep-3101-a-new-approach-to-string-formatting), but it was at least supposed to be deprecated by 3.1, which was released some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this approach because you don't have to repeat yourself by referencing the variable twice:

```
alpha = 123
print 'The answer is {alpha}'.format(**locals())
```

Comment: But i guess it's very slow - unpacking a possibly big dict for the params.

Comment: @warwaruk writing to std out is the limiting factor, printing a string takes 10 times longer than formatting it, furthermore locals() returns a reference so I think this method is pretty fast

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between this in Ruby:

```
print "foo is #{bar}."
```

And these in Python:

```
print "foo is {bar}".format(bar=bar)
```

In the Ruby example, `bar` is *evaluated*
In the Python example, `bar` is just a key to the dictionary

In the case that you are just using variables the behave more or less the same, but in general, converting Ruby to Python isn't quite so simple

Comment: This is incorrect since 3.6. We now have `print(f"foo is #{bar}")`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. Python, in my opinion, has great support for string formatting, replacements and operators.

This might be helpful:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [**Template Strings**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) like this:

```py
from string import Template
s = Template('$who likes $what')
s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
# 'tim likes kung pao'
```

This works really well for when you want to build the string template ahead of time and inject the variable elsewhere

**See Also**: [PEP 292 – Simpler String Substitutions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0292/)

Answer (score -1):

Almost every other answer didn't work for me. Probably it's because I'm on Python3.5. The only thing which worked is:

```
 print("Foobar is %s%s" %('Foo','bar',))
```