# How add variable values to string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 441, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How can i add a variable to my header?
I'm trying to send a web request with cookies but i don't know how to add variables to the header part
code:

```
headersx = {
    """
    'cookie': '__cfduid='%s'; PHPSESSID='%s'; lang=de; CF-RAY='%s',
    """
    %(cfuid, phpid, cfray)
}

response = requests.get('https://10minutemail.net/', headers=headersx)
```

Comment: You can easily [interpolate strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788472/does-python-has-a-similar-variable-interpolation-like-string-var-in-ruby) or [concatenate them](https://www.google.com/search?q=string+concatenation+python) using the `+` operator. Is there anything else that needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this something like this :

```
headersx = {
    'cookie': '__cfduid={}; PHPSESSID={}; lang=de; CF-RAY={}'.format(cfuid, phpid, cfray)
}
```

Alternatively, using [String Formatting](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html), you can do something like this :

```
headersx = {
    'cookie': '__cfduid=%s; PHPSESSID=%s; lang=de; CF-RAY=%s' % (cfuid, phpid, cfray)
}
```

For `cfuid = 'a'`, `phpid = 'b'` and `cfray = 'c'`, the headersx dictionary will result in  :

```
{'cookie': '__cfduid=a; PHPSESSID=b; lang=de; CF-RAY=c'}
```

**Note** that **dictionary** needs to have **key value pairs** separated by **colon(:)** .

Answer (score -1):

When creating a dictionary, you shouldn't put the whole `key : value` into a single string.

```
headersx = {
    'cookie': '__cfduid='%s'; PHPSESSID='%s'; lang=de; CF-RAY='%s'%(cfuid, phpid, cfray)
}
```